# Samsung series 9 np900x4c-a03us Dual boot windows 7

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, dual-boot, windows-7, bios

how do i get USB install of 12.04 installed?

how do i change the BIOS?

how do i partition the disk for dual boot?

Web instructions for USB ISO bootable image were confusing.

Series 9 has new, UEFI compatible BIOS - there is a gotcha involving "fast BIOS Mode"

The native windows install included 2 partitions that were hard to get rid of:

1. 21GB NTFS for "Samsung-rec"  ... recovery
2. 8GB       for Hibernation

both of the above were hard to get rid of in windows.

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Not everybody out here have the same laptop as yours. Why the creating ISO is confusing, what is hard disk type (ssd?) how much storage do you have, how is partition table, Have you read the manual regarding BIOS (generally provided by the manufacturer)

Comment: i gave answer to my own FAQ - unable to POST.

Comment: edit your question and give us informations

Comment: full answer here .. http://rowntreerob.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/samsung-series-9-np900x4c-a03us-win-7-ubuntu-12-04-dual-boot/

Comment: do you want to provide information on how to install ubuntu this particular laptop? I couldn't figure out what is your question actually

Comment: yeah.. i want to provide information..
when i read all the existing docs on this particular ultrabook, there were some big gaps in the quality of the information. As you can see in 'wordpress' link, i wanted to answer my own question but , the site does not let a noob do that. So i copied the answer to  my own blog.

Answer (score 4):

Dual Boot Win7 and 12.04 putting MBR with Grub2 into /dev/sda.

With this answer, each time that i boot, i get the grub2 boot menu listing options for 12.04 and Win7.

The SSD on this system is 256G and, from the OEM Win7 install, i wanted to get rid of the Hibernate and the Recovery Partitions , reclaiming and additional 30GB of space to allocate between Win7 and 12.04.

**STEPS for INSTALL**

on Win7, use 'DISKPART' app in a shell to reduce the size of the main, C partition from 208GB to 100GB. You can use the **"shrink querymax"** to evaluate how much you can reduce the C:\ partition. Mine said i could go down to 100G from 208GB so, in a couple of cycles in the shell, using shrink, i freed up about 105GB .

When i left windows to boot from the USB stick, i had:

```
1. about 100 GB unalloacted,
2. 100Mg in the SYSTEM partition - for Win7
3. 100GB in the C:\ partition    - for Win7
4. 8GB Hibernate -  unwanted, how to delete? answer is below
5. 21GB Recovery -  unwanted, windows restore/recovery will be manual - how to delete?
```

**With Care, create the USB stick bootable on drive with > 4GB**

Lots of misinformation on the WEB! I wasted 6 hours on this one.

```
1. Format a USB drive using step #4 - http://www.ehow.com/how_5937471_format-usb-flash-drive-dos.html
2. Download the 64b, AMD Desktop linux iso - http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/
3. Download/install Unetbootin - http://http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
4. Tell the Unet dialog that you want to use the downloaded ISO to copy to the formatted USB
```

**Make required changes to Default samsung BIOS BEFORE trying to change the BOOT order**

1. TURN OFF bios/advanced/fast BIOS mode

i wasted alot of time here too. I guess that they did something to maximize wake from sleep to the SSD but, it prevents you from booting a USB. Turn it OFF.

1. DISABLE - bios/boot/UEFI mode boot

-EDIT :  i use Win7 and UEFI is disable

**Change Boot order in BIOS**

this is standard reorder of boot options.

USB HHD should preceed the hard drive.

Insert the USB stick into one of the 2, USB slots on the right-hand side.

Boot and you should go into the well documented Ubuntu install dialogs.

In the UBUNTU system that comes up, start **‘gparted’** in order to deallocate additional space. In Dashhome, the upperleft icon in Unity, i think u can search for “Gparted”. It will come up showing 4 windows partions ( 2 that you need to keep are the **100Mg SYSTEM** , and the big **C:\ partition** at around 100GB ).

```
1. Use GParted to delete “Recovery 21 GB”
2. use GParted to delete “Hibernate 8 GB”
```

You are now ready to do the install. At this point , i had about 145GB for the Ubuntu install. Just click the install icon on the main screen and you are away on the install dialog.

Allocated the following in a new, Extended partition created during the ubuntu install where i selected the 3rd option to instruct it on partition details:

```
/boot logical 500Mg
/ (root) logical 40GB
/home logical 80GB
```

NOTE: 20GB remained unallocated after the above were taken from the available disk.

Note: no swap! what with 8GB ram. i will worry about swap later.

EDIT - Mainline kernel. Note that in the months following the install, my only complaints were occaisional UI freezes and the kernel support for Intel integrated HD4000 chipset. Had alot of problems with WebGL/Chrome browser. Solved the problems by upgrading the kernel to relatively recent ubuntu mainline kernel and by using the 'chrome-beta' release of the browser.

Comment: Isn't the 8GB hibernate partition needed for standing by in windows? To @rowntreerob - does everything work fine in Windows with that partition change?

Comment: i dont use windows very much. Absent that partition there will be no recovery options of some kinds. I can live with that and wanted space.